# How to get string from specific "values" folder?

Tags: android

For example: I have a multi-language app and I want to get some string from random language and user have to guess what language it is.
How to get single string from other language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language-specific strings the app uses depends on the system local which is set up in the android system ([Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)). So Android automatically pics up the correct value. You cannot hardcode which specific (or random) value to be used.

One way to get things done is to change the local setting of android programmatically:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    getResources().getString(R.string.local_string);
```

In this case the only thing to do is to shuffle the local identifier. Of course you should safe an instance of local right before changing it, so that you can reset it to original state. Good luck ;)

**edit:**
here is some dirty code I wrote to verify:

```
    Locale orgLocal = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    String[] availLocales = { "fr", "de", "en" };
    Locale tempLocale = new Locale(availLocales[new Random().nextInt(availLocales.length)]);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = tempLocale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    String randLangString = getResources().getString(R.string.local_string);
    config.locale = orgLocal;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    Toast.makeText(this, randLangString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Use this Code to change the Language Setting**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("kn");
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
getResources().getString(R.string.local_string);
```

**Then For Support all type of language use** 
**Unicode Fonts like-- "ARIALUNI.TTF" Arial Unicode Font(copy into asset folder)**

```
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ARIALUNI.TTF");  TextView tv1.setTypeface(font);
tv1.setText(R.string.txt);
```

**Take R.string.text value from values-en-for english and values-kn folder for kannada language **

Answer (score 0):

Its quite surprising and belive to that we can only alter configuration by to enable which language we want . Depending on need

```
Locale locale;
                  locale = new Locale("fr","FR");


        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        this.getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, this.getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```